# How to install wget with debug support on homebrew?

Tags: macos, homebrew, wget

`wget` does not support `-d` on homebrew default installation. How to install wget with debug support on homebrew? Thanks.

```
$ wget -d -o/tmp/log -qO- http://httpbin.org/get
Debugging support not compiled in. Ignoring --debug flag.
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for the records: After uninstalling wget install it with:

```
brew install wget --with-debug
```

Source: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/wget.rb

Comment: This seems to no longer work, seems they removed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're feeling like going with a less convoluted way of installing packages rather than using `Homebrew` then maybe try `MacPorts`.

```
$ sudo port install wget

--->  Computing dependencies for wget
--->  Cleaning wget
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
--->  No broken files found.
```

*Done!*

The **MacPorts** of **wget** version supports the ***debug flag*** (`-d`) out of the box:

```
$ wget -d -o/tmp/log -qO- http://httpbin.org/get
Setting --output-file (logfile) to /tmp/log
Setting --output-file (logfile) to /tmp/log
Setting --quiet (quiet) to 1
Setting --quiet (quiet) to 1
Setting --output-document (outputdocument) to -
Setting --output-document (outputdocument) to -
{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "identity", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "Wget/1.19.4 (darwin17.3.0)"
  }, 
  "origin": "23.198.166.150", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/get"
}

$ wget --version
GNU Wget 1.19.4 built on darwin17.3.0.
```

Comment: I am not using MacPorts. It has its own set of problems that drives me away from it some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to install wget with the debug support via Homebrew.

Run `brew edit wget` to access the formula code, add `"--enable-debug"` in the configuration section, save, then run `brew install --build-from-source wget`

Other configuration options can also be enabled or disabled this way (only do not forget to add a library to the "depends_on" section if you enable one in the configuration).

Answer (score 0):

It has debug enabled by default now, you don't need to edit the formula or pass a flag.